# Elastic Collision on iphone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, game-physics

I want to learn elastic collision.like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Elastischer_sto%C3%9F_2D.gif) animation, 
first of all ,what should i learn for iphone game development? is there any good step by step tutorial to start with?

[image: this is the animation similar to with i want to start building games]

Answer (score 4):

For such kind of collisions you can use box2d it is good physical engine, that take care about such things. You just have to set up it. I think, you can find many articles about using box2d with cocos2d with google